# insertAdjacentHTML displaying [object, Object] for Functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx, react-component

I have some JSX below that gets injected into the DOM before the `firstComment` element.

Inside are a couple functions that simply return svgs. When the browser runs the `thumbsUp()` and `thumbsDown()` functions, they show up as `[object Object]` `[object Object]`.

How can I get this code working, without directly replacing the functions with the svgs? I'm open to using a different method than insertAdjacentHTML if need be.

```js
const postComment = (inputValue) =>
{
  const d1 = document.getElementById('firstComment')
  d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin',
    ` 
      <div>
        <div class="comment-avatar"></div>
          <div class="comment-container">
            <h5 class="commentorName">Guest</h5>
            <div class="dateOfComment">Just Now</div>
            <p class="comment">${inputValue}</p>
            <div class="thumbs">
              <span class="thumbsUpIcon">
                ${thumbsUp(16)}
              </span>
              <span class="thumbsDownIcon">
                ${thumbsDown(16)}
              </span>
            </div>
            <p class="replyText">REPLY</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    `
  )
}
```

Functions

```
const thumbsUp = (width) => {
  return (
    <svg width={width} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M198 448h172c15.7 0 28.6-9.6 34.2-23.4l57.1-135.4c1.7-4.4 2.6-9 2.6-14v-38.6c0-21.1-17-44.6-37.8-44.6H306.9l18-81.5.6-6c0-7.9-3.2-15.1-8.3-20.3L297 64 171 191.3c-6.8 6.9-11 16.5-11 27.1v192c0 21.1 17.2 37.6 38 37.6zM48 224h64v224H48z"/></svg>
    ) 
}

const thumbsDown = (width) => {
    return (
      <svg width={width} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M314 64H142c-15.7 0-28.6 9.6-34.2 23.4L50.6 222.8c-1.7 4.4-2.6 9-2.6 14v38.6c0 21.1 17 44.6 37.8 44.6h119.3l-18 81.5-.6 6c0 7.9 3.2 15.1 8.3 20.3l20 20.1L341 320.7c6.8-6.9 11-16.5 11-27.1v-192c0-21.1-17.2-37.6-38-37.6zM400 64h64v224h-64z"/></svg>
      ) 
  }
```

Comment: Can you please post the `thumbsUp` function and `thumbsDown` function in your question too.

Comment: Sure. But it's just like I said. All they do is return the svg. I use them in many places in the app so the function works as intended.

Comment: If you turn the returned SVG code into a string, does that work? 
For example: `const thumbsUp = (width) => {  return '<svg></svg>'}`.

Comment: @JustinFeakes That works, but kind of destroys my code in all other areas where I'm importing that function.

Comment: Hmm, where you're calling ${thumbsUp(16)}, can you convert it to a string and leave your function untouched? Eg `${thumbsUp(16).toString()}`

Comment: @JustinFeakes Unfortunately, still get [object Object] using toString()

Comment: wait, what? you're inserting a react component into the dom using dom methods? that seems... odd. Am i just misunderstanding the question? Javascript template literals create strings... a react component is not a string. Why are you doing this with dom methods outside of the normal react flow?

Comment: That is not valid Javascript. It looks like some JSX-like syntax, but your question neither mentions nor tags JSX.

Comment: @user400654 What would the "normal react flow" way of doing this be?

Comment: @connexo it did, before someone edited it out. rolled it back

Comment: @RobertC It depends. If this portion of the page isn't part of the react app controlling the rest of the page, there are a few ways of solving that specifically. If it IS part of the react app, then the approach should be pretty straight forward. If react isn't even on that page... you just need a different set of functions that aren't react components. That might be the better alternative in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be solved (without breaking other sections of code that import the svgs) by having two separate returns in the thumbs functions, and having an argument as a check. Setting insert to true returns the svg as a string, and excluding the argument in the function call returns the normal svg.

Not sure it's optimal, but it works.

```
const thumbsDown = (width, insert) => {
  if (insert) {
    return (
      `<svg width=${width} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M314 64H142c-15.7 0-28.6 9.6-34.2 23.4L50.6 222.8c-1.7 4.4-2.6 9-2.6 14v38.6c0 21.1 17 44.6 37.8 44.6h119.3l-18 81.5-.6 6c0 7.9 3.2 15.1 8.3 20.3l20 20.1L341 320.7c6.8-6.9 11-16.5 11-27.1v-192c0-21.1-17.2-37.6-38-37.6zM400 64h64v224h-64z"/></svg>`
    ) 
  } 
    return (
      <svg width={width} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M314 64H142c-15.7 0-28.6 9.6-34.2 23.4L50.6 222.8c-1.7 4.4-2.6 9-2.6 14v38.6c0 21.1 17 44.6 37.8 44.6h119.3l-18 81.5-.6 6c0 7.9 3.2 15.1 8.3 20.3l20 20.1L341 320.7c6.8-6.9 11-16.5 11-27.1v-192c0-21.1-17.2-37.6-38-37.6zM400 64h64v224h-64z"/></svg>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the svg code returned by the `thumbsUp`/`thumbsDown` functions in backticks making them into template literals, it seems to return the svg's you expect. I wasn't getting the [object Object] result you described, but those functions don't return the svg correctly in the snippet editor for me without them.

```js
const postComment = (inputValue) =>
{
  const d1 = document.getElementById('firstComment')
  d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin',
    ` 
      <div>
        <div class="comment-avatar"></div>
          <div class="comment-container">
            <h5 class="commentorName">Guest</h5>
            <div class="dateOfComment">Just Now</div>
            <p class="comment">${inputValue}</p>
            <div class="thumbs">
              <span class="thumbsUpIcon">
                ${thumbsUp(16)}
              </span>
              <span class="thumbsDownIcon">
                ${thumbsDown(16)}
              </span>
            </div>
            <p class="replyText">REPLY</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    `
  )
}

const thumbsUp = (width) => {
  return (
    `<svg width=${width} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M198 448h172c15.7 0 28.6-9.6 34.2-23.4l57.1-135.4c1.7-4.4 2.6-9 2.6-14v-38.6c0-21.1-17-44.6-37.8-44.6H306.9l18-81.5.6-6c0-7.9-3.2-15.1-8.3-20.3L297 64 171 191.3c-6.8 6.9-11 16.5-11 27.1v192c0 21.1 17.2 37.6 38 37.6zM48 224h64v224H48z"/></svg>`
    ) 
}

const thumbsDown = (width) => {
    return (
      `<svg width=${width} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M314 64H142c-15.7 0-28.6 9.6-34.2 23.4L50.6 222.8c-1.7 4.4-2.6 9-2.6 14v38.6c0 21.1 17 44.6 37.8 44.6h119.3l-18 81.5-.6 6c0 7.9 3.2 15.1 8.3 20.3l20 20.1L341 320.7c6.8-6.9 11-16.5 11-27.1v-192c0-21.1-17.2-37.6-38-37.6zM400 64h64v224h-64z"/></svg>`
      ) 
}

postComment('hello whirled')
```

```html
<div id='firstComment'></div>
```

Comment: Yes, this does work, but also destroys all the other areas in my code importing the thumbs svgs.

Comment: How is your code different in the other places it calls the variable width svg functions?

Comment: Other places of the code isn't inserting any html. The function was originally made just to replace the long svg text, to make my react components more readable. So the difference is just that in this case I'm calling the thumbs function inside some html to insert.

Comment: Ah, well calling those functions from inside the render method of a React component is interpreted differently than inserting them into the using vanilla JS. I can't tell without seeing all your code, but I wonder why you can't produce the same behavior using React's APIs rather than `insertAdjacentHTML`. If you show us your React components maybe we can find a solution like that. Otherwise your answer with two returns seems like an OK option

Answer (score -1):

You can just create a `div` element using the [createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) method and then push your html content to that div using the [innerHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property. You can now use the [insertAdjacentElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) method to render your HTML on your `firstComment` element.

---

Run the following **Code Snippet** or you can check this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/yudpt5L6/12/)** for a practical example of the above approach:

```js
/* JavaScript */
let div = document.getElementById("firstComment");

const thumbsUp = (width) => {
 return `<svg width=${width} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M198 448h172c15.7 0 28.6-9.6 34.2-23.4l57.1-135.4c1.7-4.4 2.6-9 2.6-14v-38.6c0-21.1-17-44.6-37.8-44.6H306.9l18-81.5.6-6c0-7.9-3.2-15.1-8.3-20.3L297 64 171 191.3c-6.8 6.9-11 16.5-11 27.1v192c0 21.1 17.2 37.6 38 37.6zM48 224h64v224H48z"/></svg>`
}
const thumbsDown = (width) => {
 return `<svg width=${width} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M314 64H142c-15.7 0-28.6 9.6-34.2 23.4L50.6 222.8c-1.7 4.4-2.6 9-2.6 14v38.6c0 21.1 17 44.6 37.8 44.6h119.3l-18 81.5-.6 6c0 7.9 3.2 15.1 8.3 20.3l20 20.1L341 320.7c6.8-6.9 11-16.5 11-27.1v-192c0-21.1-17.2-37.6-38-37.6zM400 64h64v224h-64z"/></svg>`
}

const htmlContent = document.createElement("div");
htmlContent.innerHTML = `
   <div class="comment-avatar"></div>
   <div class="comment-container">
    <h5 class="commentorName">Guest</h5>
    <div class="dateOfComment">Just Now</div>
    <p class="comment">SomeValue</p>
    <div class="thumbs">
     <span class="thumbsUpIcon">
      ${thumbsUp(16)}
     </span>
     <span class="thumbsDownIcon">
      ${thumbsDown(16)}
     </span>
    </div>
    <p class="replyText">REPLY</p>
   </div>
`;

div.insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin", htmlContent);
```

```css
/* CSS */
html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="firstComment"></div>
```